# Unity with PlayFab: How to Save Statistic into a Integer

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, unity-game-engine

I use the PlayFab service to register my users and log them in. I also use it to store statistics.

With this function/void I request my data from the server.

```
public void GetStats()
{
    var request = new GetPlayerStatisticsRequest();
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerStatistics(request, GetStatsSucces, GetStatsError);
}
```

And when I have successfully received my data, I will "fetch" the data with this method

```
public void GetStatsSucces(GetPlayerStatisticsResult result)
{
    print("Stats wurden empfangen");

    foreach (var stats in result.Statistics)
    {
        switch (stats.StatisticName)
        {
            case "Number":
                print("Number: " + stats.Value);
                number = stats.Value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good.

I print out the number and get my value. The number is `150000`.

And now we come to my problem. I want the integer `number` to store the number I get. Therefore, `number = stats.value;`

But if I read the integer then the integer is `0` instead of `150000`.

I hope you guys can help me, because I really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Where is your "number" declared? And if you put The log below the "number" variable assignation, showing stats.Value + number, they are different?

Comment: Please add the rest of your code .. with the current information it is impossible to find the issue/a solution